# How to nested list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new list from 2 lists using list comprehension

```
>>> l = ['%sdummy1', '%sdummy2']
>>> z = ['new1', 'new2']
```

With basic list comprehension knowledge I can get the list below

```
>>> x = [item % 'new1' for item in l]
['new1dummy1', 'new1dummy2']
>>>
```

but how can I iterate over the "z" and get the list below?

```
['new1dummy1', 'new1dummy2', 'new2dummy1', 'new2dummy2']
```

Answer (score 5):

simply with double flat list comprehension:

```
l = ['%sdummy1', '%sdummy2']
z = ['new1', 'new2']

result = [x % y for x in l for y in z]
```

result:

```
['new1dummy1', 'new2dummy1', 'new1dummy2', 'new2dummy2']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `for _ in __` statements in a single comprehension

```
x = [item % tag for item in l for tag in z]
```